# Value not set correctly with JavaScript and Primefaces

Tags: javascript, html, jsf, primefaces

im sending a variable with a JS to an inputtext. then when the value has been set i click on a p:commandButton to call a method that uses that value but the value that passes is blank... although the js sent the value to the input and i see it... it takes it as blank. if i input the value myself it does read it in the method... otherwhise it does not... any ideas?
here's my code as much resumed as i can get it (it's kind of long):

XHTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModalId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header bg-warning">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><b>#{msg.html32}</b></h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                   <center style="font-size: 14px">#{msg.html31}</center>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p:commandLink  action="#{bd.setId(dotcalpro.id)}"  styleClass="btn btn-md btn-info" value="#{msg.htmlborrar}" immediate="true" update="tbResult, growl" accesskey="r" onclick="modalIdhide()"/>
                    <p:spacer height="5"/>
                    <p:commandLink  styleClass="btn btn-md btn-info" value="#{msg.html48}" immediate="true" update="tbResult, growl" onclick="modalIdhide()"/>
                   </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>  

        <p:column width="60">  
        <f:facet name="header">#{msg.dotcalprotbver}</f:facet> 
        <center>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs"
        onclick="detalle('#{tb.zid}'); modalIdshow();" >
        <i class="fa fa-search fa-2x"></i>
        </button>
        </center>
        </p:column>
```

JS:

```
function detalle(vT0){
    document.getElementById("formdotcalpro:id").value= rTrim(vT0);
    updateInput('formdotcalpro:id', '#F2F2F2')
    //alert(document.getElementById("formdotcalpro:id").value);
    var x = document.getElementById("formdotcalpro:id").value;
    alert("valor: " + x)
}

//Modal id show
function modalIdshow(){
    $("#myModalId").modal();
}


//Modal id hide
function modalIdhide(){
    $("#myModalId").modal('hide');
}
```

Bean:

```
/**
 * Setea tipo de valor de la meta para busqueda
 * @param next
 */
public void setId(String id){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("id", id);
    System.out.println("valor : " + id);
}
```

I say again just in case i have resumed the code as much as posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i found some sort of solution with my sesion variable... it worked but not quite sure if it's the rigth aproach.

just added this in my Bean class:

```
/**
 * Setea tipo de valor de la meta para busqueda
 * @param next
 */
public void setId(String id){
    HttpServletRequest rq = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String idval = rq.getParameter("formdotcalpro:id");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("id", idval);
    //System.out.println("valor : " + idval);
}
```

I still welcome another point of view to this problem if you have the time.